# Is it possible to modify data from UNION query in this way?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

The data that came out of the UNION query I wrote came out like this.

```
COLUMNS1     COLUMNS2       DATE1                  DATE2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 A              B            2022-01-10 05:40:12      NULL
 A              B             NULL                  2022-01-25 12:40:00
 C              D            2022-01-15 05:40:12      NULL
 C              D             NULL                  2022-01-17 12:40:00
 ...
```

How can I get the above data to come out as a query?

```
COLUMNS1       COLUMNS2       DATE1                  DATE2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 A              B            2022-01-10 05:40:12    2022-01-25 12:40:00
 C              D            2022-01-15 05:40:12    2022-01-17 12:40:00
....
```

Similarly, you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN , but I don't want to use it.

It seems very simple, but I can't find an answer at all. Maybe it's impossible, but am I trying?

Comment: GROUP BY and some aggregate function (MAX, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the results of your query and aggregate the date columns, such as:

```
select COLUMNS1, COLUMNS2,
  max(DATE1) DATE1,
  max(DATE2) DATE2
from (...)t
group by COLUMNS1, COLUMNS2;
```

Comment: Thanks.. why didn't I think of MAX func ;(